# Как удалить или остановить поток?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как удалить или остановить поток, чтобы выполнить определенное действие и запустить (желательно удалить)?

Comment: создайте функцию завершения потока на самом классе потока (destructor)

Comment: @Saidolim так себе совет. Поток не должен заниматься менеджментом себя.

Comment: Почитайте [эту статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133413/). Вкратце, ваш поток должен проверять "а не прерван ли я?" и если "прерван" - завершить свою работу сам, так как он умеет. Освободив ресурсы, откатив транзакции и прочее.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Все потоки нужно прерывать при помощи метода `interrupt()`. 
В самом потоке, который возможно будет прерван - нужно устанавливать проверки `isInterrupted()` во всех ключевых точках (где это необходимо) и обрабатывать соответственно. 
Ну это если в двух словах, а так лучше прочтите что-то по типу [этой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164487/) статьи на Хабре.

Состряпал пример:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final HelloThread helloThread = new HelloThread(); //final - для таймера
        helloThread.start();

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Interrupting thread...");
                helloThread.interrupt();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
        System.out.println("Thread main still work");

    }
}

class HelloThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                if (!isInterrupted()) {//isInterrupted проверять в любых ключевых точках,
                    // где можно обработать прерывание потока
                    if(i%5==1) System.out.println("Hello from a thread! " + i);
                } else {
                    throw new InterruptedException(); //бросаем исключение в таких случаях как этот (циклы)
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread is interrupted"); //Закрываем все стримы если есть
        }

        //Не забывайте, что поток завершается когда нечего испонять
        System.out.println("Nothing to say"); //и окончательно он завершится после этой строки
    }
}
```

Вообще в java doc не рекомендуют пользоваться deprecated методами (такими как `Thread.stop()`). Метод `Thread.stop()` убивает поток не обрабатывая и самое главное -

> поток может быть «убит» во время выполнения операции, обрыв которой на полуслове оставит некоторый объект в неправильном состоянии, что приведет к появлению трудноотлавливаемой и случайным образом возникающей ошибке

(цитата из все той-же [статьи](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164487/) на Хабре)

Comment: Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Comment: Прям таки все? А все ли потоки можно прервать вызовом `interrupt`?

Comment: @a_gura, да, если пользоваться depricated методом `stop()`, то, как замечают разработчики java, он может оставить объекты в памяти в неправильном состоянии. Это может привести к трудно отлавливаемым багам, которые будут возникать "внезапно".